# Skipping Nan values when counting consecutive values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe and I am trying to count the consecutive `winners`
The problem is there are some 'NaN' values interspersed within the column values, that I would like to skip when trying to count consecutive `winners`

```
                   week_1  week_2  week_3  week_4  week_5  week_6  \
Year                                                                     
2000 Arizona Cardinals   loser  winner   loser   loser  winner   loser   
     Atlanta Falcons     winner  loser  winner   loser   loser   loser   
     Baltimore Ravens    winner  NaN   winner  winner  winner  winner   
     Buffalo Bills       NaN     winner   loser   loser   loser  winner   
     Carolina Panthers   loser  winner   loser   loser  winner   loser
```

I can use `df3 = df.shift(-1, axis =1).isin(['winner'])`
to make the comparisons, but this is not going to skip the `NaN` values.

So something like this:

```
Baltimore Ravens    winner  NaN   winner
```

which should count for as consecutive values will be skipped.

Comment: Easiest approach might be to go by row and drop `NaN` values. What is your ultimate goal though? Are you counting longest streak for each team and year?

Comment: Ultimate goal is conditional probabilities: Give two consecutive wins, prob of winning or losing etc for various wins and losses.  It's going to be part of a Markov chain model for all 17 weeks.

Comment: Is the fact that there was a bye week a variable in your algorithm? If not, it's probably easiest to just make it 16 weeks and throw out all bye weeks. Otherwise.you'd have to encode the NaN as something anyway.

Comment: I can just make a copy of the df so that I can retain the bye week portion for the analysis I want to do with the bye-week. 
How would you propose making it just 16 weeks and getting rid of the 'NAN' values? That should work! 
This is a multindex df so,  df[df_location].head() doesn't seem to be working
I also just tried : df.loc[df.notnull()]. That comes back with an error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to drop your `NaN` values and shift values, you can use `apply` along axis 1 and `dropna`. You have to do a little bit of finagling though to shift the values:

```
no_bye = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
no_bye.columns = ['game_' + str(n+1) for n in range(16)]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am testing out the code now.
I am a little confused about the `.reset_index(drop = True)` portion.
So the `apply` function is applied horizontally, dropping any nan values within each row.
So are the columns considered the `index` in this case?

Comment: Yes index is columns in this case. You need to reset the index to remove the original columns: `'week_1', 'week_2'...`. Otherwise when `apply` puts the columns back together they'll still be in the original weeks. This essentially scoots the values forward after dropping nan values.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure out a vectorized solution, but didn't manage.
This may be easily solved by a simple python loop over each row:

```
def find_wins(x):
    mw = 0
    c = 0
    for e in x.dropna():
        c = c + 1 if e == 'winner' else 0
        mw = max(mw, c)
    return mw

res = df.apply(find_wins, axis=1)
```

with `df` your original dataframe, this returns the following `res` `Series`:

```
year             
2000  Arizona Cardinals    1
      Atlanta Falcons      1
      Baltimore Ravens     5
      Buffalo Bills        1
      Carolina Panthers    1
dtype: int64
```

where each element is maximum numbers of consecutive wins (nan skipped).

The point here is just do use `x.dropna()` to drop the `nan` values before looping on each row and count the consecutive `'winner'`.